# How to delete row from table later than date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table:

```
MyTable:
-Id int primary key
-Name varchar(MAX)
-Deleted bit
```

Now i want delete rows created later that `15.12.2014`. But how can you see i don't have a any date columns in my table.
It's possible to do in MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restore the backup you have from `15.12.2014` to a new database and then you can delete the rows from your production database that does not exist in your restored backup database.

There is no hidden datetime information in the table that you can use.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's sad couse i don't have backups.